# Spot light cone direction rotation and orientation inversion

Tags: math, opengl

I am working on Spot light transformation system in OpenGL.As it is known ,Spot light has by default position and cone direction.But in my implementation it also has to have rotation and orientation.In this case **rotation** -local rotation of light cone while **orientation** - world rotation of the cone after the local rotation has been applied.

I got all kind of axis flip problem during this work which partly stem from the fact that glm::lookAt method inverts "eye" vector of the output matrix.Now all fine except that I have to invert final direction vector y and z parts in order to get spot light cone face not the inverse direction:

```
            lookatMatr[2].y =-  lookatMatr[2].y;
    lookatMatr[2].z =-  lookatMatr[2].z;
```

I can't figure out 2 things :

1 .How can do it so that I don't need to do the inversion at the end.
 2 .Why the inversion needed only for Y and Z axis.

Here is the full code of the transformation:

```
    glm::vec4 worldPos = WorldMatr *  _pos ;
    glm::vec4 worldDir = WorldMatr  *  glm::vec4( _lightDir,1) ; 
    glm::vec4 worldUp  = WorldMatr  *  glm::vec4(Y_AXIS,1) ; 


    //first construct lookat matrix to get direction vector
    glm::mat4 lookatMatr =  glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(worldPos),glm::vec3(worldDir),glm::vec3(worldUp)) ;

            //rotate locally :
    lookatMatr =  glm::rotate(lookatMatr,30.0f,X_AXIS) ;
    lookatMatr =  glm::rotate(lookatMatr,0.0f,Y_AXIS) ;
    lookatMatr =  glm::rotate(lookatMatr,0.0f,Z_AXIS) ;

            //Orient :
    lookatMatr =  Transform().GetOrientationMatrix() * ( lookatMatr );

    _posOut=  worldPos ;
//  lookatMatr[2].x =-  lookatMatr[2].x;//why only Y and Z to be inverted?
    lookatMatr[2].y =-  lookatMatr[2].y;
    lookatMatr[2].z =-  lookatMatr[2].z;
    _dirOut=  ( lookatMatr[2])   ;
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok , as was suggested below , I set w part of _lightDir to be zero and now doing this:

```
_dirOut=World * Transform().GetOrientationMatrix() *  rotMatr *   glm::vec4( _lightDir,0);
```

It shows the light cone correctly but its direction is flipped on X axis now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you must have in mind is that `lookAt` produces an inverted matrix. This matrix is the system transform that transforms vectors from world space to camera space. This is equal to the model transformation that would move the camera from its position in world space to the origin. Not vice versa.

Vectors that describe directions must have a 0 in their w-component. This results in skipping the translation part of matrices. Correct your definitions of `worldDir` and `worldUp`.

However, you really don't need a lookAt matrix. Instead you should just take the `worldDir` and perform transformations on this vector. So the overall direction would be:

```
_dirOut = 
    WorldMatr * OrientationMatrix * LocalRotationMatrix * glm::vec4(_lightDir, 0);
```

You can either premultiply the matrices and then perform one transformation of the vector or you can transform the vector three times (firstly with the LocalRotationMatrix and so on).

Comment: Your solution doesn't work.In such a case local rotation is not local.For example if I rotate (local) around Z axis , the cone direction shoudn't change.But with the approach as you specify it does change.

Comment: Ok , I used quaternion for local rotation calc and it didn't work ok.Now changed to regular rotation and it does.But it is flipped on X axis.So  if I flip"_dirOut.x" it faces the right direction.Any ideas?

Comment: Well ,probably it is right behavior as my source of emulation is left handed coord system.Thanks.

Comment: If your matrices are basically rotations and translations, handedness does not play a role. The flip must be caused by any of your matrices. Check if one of them contains a negative scaling factor. Btw, please accept the answer if it answers the question. This applies for many of your other questions as well.